# How make the mail merge faster

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have an Excel file which is calculating something and in the end I transfer data to a Word file with mail merge to make a report out of it. Everything is working perfectly, but the procedure is becoming slower and slower since I am adding more and more variables into the report. The procedure starts with calculating the variables in a VBA code, and then the variables are stored in an Excel sheet, and then the Word file is called, etc. For example, to store the variables:

```
.
.
.

Dim r As Long

With Worksheets("Variabeles")


r = 2

.Range("A" & r).Value = "variableA"
.Range("B" & r).Value = Range("variableA").Value
r = r + 1

.Range("A" & r).Value = "variableB"
.Range("B" & r).Value = Range("variableB").Value
r = r + 1
.
.
.
```

And this goes on to store all variable in the worksheet. I calculated the run time for the whole procedure, and about 80% of time is spent to store the data. Is there any way that I can speed up this part?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your code. Also, is `"variableA"` supposed to be a string or the name of your variable?

Comment: Nothing about the code snippet you've posted indicates anything to do with mailmerge.